# how to define stateful icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi It's kind of sounds wired question..

There are three dart pages in my app. and they have same appbar in commonly but just one thing that I want to make it differently in each pages that is icon shows depends on each pages.. how to make make it? I guess it have to use provider or kinda state management methods.. but I don't get it. How to make it?,,

some example my code below

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({Key? key, required Color backgroundColor, required List<Chip> actions, required Icon leading}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  PreferredSizeWidget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.home_filled,

        size: 40,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      actions: [
        Chip(label: Text('\$${ego}'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

additionally I want to use the codes above in sevaral pages and just make it show differently icon in leading in code above at the position in each pages.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It might look a bit dumb. But when I was trying to do the thing you're attempting rn, I felt like it's the easiest way to achieve it. But here's the trick I'm talking about ->

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
 MyAppBar(
   {Key? key,
   required Color backgroundColor,
   required List<Chip> actions,
   required Icon leadingIcon})
    : super(
       key: key,
       backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
       actions: actions,
       leading: leadingIcon,
      );
 }
```

You can make it totally modular and place default items by just making the variables nullable.

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
  MyAppBar(
   {Key? key,
   Color? backgroundColor,
   List<Chip>? actions,
   Icon? leadingIcon})
     : super(
         key: key,
         backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? Colors.transparent,
         actions: actions ??
            const [
              Chip(
                label: Text("Default Chip"),
                ),
              ],
         leading: leadingIcon ??
          const Icon(
            Icons.home_filled,
            size: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
            ),
       );
   }
```

Also, If you find a better and preferable way, you can help me to fix it too. Cz I know in the future I might use it if I need it. But I'm not sure if it's the right way.